# How can I proxy google maven using nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

I want to proxy google maven using nexus,I use the url `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/` for remote storage location,the repository status is `In Service-Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable`. I try to set Auto Blocking Enabled `false`,but problem still happen.

Comment: I've update to  Nexus Repo 3 ,problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Nexus Repo 2:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9508

However, your work-around SHOULD have worked. Try running a build against the repo, our support people say you might be trying to browse remote or checking the index tabs, which will not work in this case.

You can try out Nexus Repo 3 in case you aren't using it, I'd be interested to see what your mileage is there. Let me know either way if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the solution, is not use a "public" repo, but a specific repo like "http://nexusrepo/repository/Google" and not "http://nexusrepo/repository/public", and in build.gradle add this entry

`maven{
    url = "http://nexusrepo/repository/Google"
}`

I'm using version :

Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.0.0-03